# rails 4 asset pipieline is taking forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've experienced intermittent issues with rendering in development, where simple internal javascript assets can take over 30 seconds to load. Assuming I've started a brand new project, and am not waiting on any external requests to come through the backend, i don't feel it should take as long as it does. Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this may be or have any of you experienced similar issues?

Again, the issue appears to be sporadic. Just happens every couple of refreshes.